# sunspot_solr stored fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot, sunspot-solr

I have this line in searchable block

```
text :title, :stored => true
```

Am searching book title via sunspot solr. But do I really have to use stored field ?

```
:stored => true
```

as per documentation

> Stored fields allow data to be retrieved without also hitting the underlying database (usually an SQL server). They are also required for highlighting and more like this queries.
>
> Stored fields come at some performance cost in the Solr index, so use them wisely.

But I don't know when should I really use these stored fields. Because I have so many fields in searchable block. Should I make all of them as stored to avoid hitting db ? and what will be the performance cost ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sunspot maintainer here.

So long as you are using Sunspot to load ActiveRecord objects, then storing field values is recommended only for use with Solr features which require them, such as highlighting.

If you are rendering `hits` from a Sunspot search response, and not loading the `results`, then you will want to store the field values which you are rendering in your views. But for reasons I've mentioned [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13870207/154694), you should probably have a clear reason for bypassing ActiveRecord in that way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the Fields back as a Solr response, generally for Display purpose you would mark the fields as Stored.
If you want the fields only to be searchable and not to be displayed, have them indexed only.
Instead you hitting back the DB, it would be faster to it Stored and retrieved from Solr as you are performing the Search anyways.
The backdrop for using Stored on multiple fields would be the Index size would grow big as Solr has to be store the actual values. However, if the number of document count is not that high, it should not bother you.

Comment: In my app am searching book title. So I'll add title as just field and available_count as stored field since am using available count to display from solr. is it correct?

Comment: you would add the fields which you would need to display e.g. When you do a book search you would display the title, authors, available_count, description and some more in the results as in Amazon site.

Comment: No. I get the list of books from solr and I look into book model to get the title and description etc. But the available count is stored in solr so I ll use it directly. Because available count is calculated with complex query and I stored that in solr while indexing so that I dont have to run that complex query again and again. So It makes sense to store :available_count , :stored => true

Comment: yup, it would make sense. You can store the other fields as well to prevent any further DB calls if you want.